# angular - TypeError Data must be a string or a buffer while run ng serve

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

when i run angular app with ng serve at time :

```
 86% hashingcrypto.js:74
  this._handle.update(data, encoding);
               ^
TypeError: Data must be a string or a buffer
```

I use :

```
 node version : 6.11.3 
 npm version  : 3.10.10
 angular      : 4
```

Comment: The problems occurs when trying to export a file not present on the disk. check this link https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/4072#issuecomment-278626604

Comment: And what is your problem? Add new information right into your question, not in comments.

Answer (score 0):

hi. Read about your question regarding the TypeError: Data must be a String or Buffer.
Update your node from 6.11.3 to 7.4.0 as well as your npm to the latest version.
I think this must solve your problem. Also, check whether any wrong import is done.